# ItemUpdating event not firing on folder rename w/ Windows Explorer

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, event-handlers, folder, rename

I have an Item Updating event receiver that needs to fire when a document library folder is renamed.  Everything works perfect when a user renames the folder with the SharePoint UI.

However, if they rename the folder with Windows Explorer, the event receiver doesn't fire.

Interestingly, if they create a new folder w/ Windows Explorer it fires Item Added -> Item Updating -> Item Updated (using "New Folder" all through the chain).  But it doesn't fire again once they replace "New Folder" with the folder's real name.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the exact same issue. I was just going to give it up, when I thought I'd give two other event receivers a try: `ItemFileMoving` and `ItemFileMoved`. And it worked!

There is a logic to it I think, renaming and moving operations are somewhat alike.

You can see it best when you're creating a new folder from Explorer/WebDAV.
Immediately it fires

> ItemAdding -> ItemAdded -> ItemUpdating -> ItemUpdated (possibly
>   another ItemUpdating -> ItemUpdated due to RequireCheckOut or so)

Note that the name is still "New folder" at this time.
Then you can input the new folder's name and `ItemFileMoving` and `ItemFileMoved` are fired.