# How to prevent users from renaming a folder

Tags: permissions, folder, rename

I have set up a folder structure to manage documents. One requirement is to have different permissions on each folder. Basically no real magic but there is one issue. 
I need to prevent users from renaming the top folder of each area. In detail:

```
[DocumentLibrary] --> [Area1Folder]
                  --> [Area2Folder] --> [FolderStructureCreatedByEndUser]
```

I added permission Assignments to the areafolders to set the permissions for the subdfolders and documents. 
My issue is that I need to prevent the modification of the AreaFolders even if the endUsers have fullpermissions on the Area. 
I tried to prevent this by using an EventReceiver but with no success. I am able to control all filed information but not the Folder Name. :( 
Has anyone an idea how I can realize it?

Thanks in Advance

Approach so far

```
public static bool AreEqualStringObjects(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    if (obj1 == null) return obj2 == null;
    if (obj2 == null) return true;
    return obj1.ToString() == obj2.ToString();
}

public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    if(!AreEqualStringObjects(properties.BeforeProperties["FileLeafRef"], properties.ListItem["FileLeafRef"]))
    {
        string orig = properties.BeforeProperties["FileLeafRef"].ToString();
        properties.ListItem["Title"] = orig;
        properties.ListItem["FileLeafRef"] = orig;

        properties.ListItem.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: An event receiver would be the only way to go, to prevent all kinds of access to rename folders. That should be feasible. Can you please share your ER code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ItemUpdating` instead of `ItemUpdated` and set `properties.Cancel = true`.
You can add optional message using `properties.ErrorMessage`.

Edit: Now I see it's obsolete in SP2013 and you should use `properties.Status` instead.

Possible values are decribed here: [`SPEventPropertiesBase.Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventpropertiesbase.status.aspx).

Added: If error message is displayed as an Exception with CallStack make sure the following web.config are set correctly:

```
<SafeMode ... CallStack="false" ...>
```

and

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

Comment: This is a good way to solve the problem ;) Thanks for that!!! But what is the correct reaction on this by the system? I receive an error page with the following message: <nativehr>0x81020089</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>...followed by the error message. (yellow window). I was hoping that I receive the normal small modal dialog windows sharepoint itself uses.

Comment: I've only used `properties.Cancel`, but form description on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventpropertiesbase.status.aspx), setting `properties.Status` to `SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError`or `SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl`is what you need.

Comment: I did it with 'properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                    properties.ErrorMessage = "My Custom Error Message"' but received that exception page :(

Comment: Thanks for the solution, after changing the web.config parameters, everything works as expected!

Comment: Ahhh I totally forgot one important point... There is still the "Windows Explorer View", with it the users are still able to rename the folder name :( Does anyone of you knows how I can either force SharePoint to execute the, well working Event Receivers or what I can do to prevent changes through it?

Comment: Try `ItemFileMoving` event as described in [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/68920/45257).

Comment: I tried the mentioned Event Receiver but if I do any changes in Windows Explorer View, no event receiver is firing at all. (I attached the debugger at all available W3WP.exe processes). Any ideas why it is not firing?