# How to disable renaming a Document Library item using "Open with Explorer"

Tags: 2010, development, document-library, event-receivers, open-with-explorer

As you can see [here, rename event of list item via Windows Explorer is handler by ItemFileMoved event](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61295/itemupdating-event-not-firing-on-folder-rename-w-windows-explorer).

So, I was trying to prevent this edit by the usual way of preventing ItemUpdating:

```
properties.Cancel = true;
properties.ErrorMessage = "You cannot edit.";
```

While it works in the ItemUpdating event when trying to rename an item from SharePoint UI, it doesn't cancel the rename event from Windows Explorer.

Is there any other way of doing this?

And I don't mean disabling the whole possibility of opening the library with Explorer, it would be an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I've handled the operation a little too late because it works only when handling the event `ItemFileMoving` not <strike>`ItemFileMoved`</strike>.

It's as simple as that:

```
properties.Cancel = true;
```

because the `ErrorMessage` won't be displayed in Explorer.

The default Windows error message looks like this:
[image]